# Databound DropDownList Not Populating (No errors)

Tags: c#, asp.net

My databound dropdownlist is not populating, I've looked at other threads here and they haven't seem to help. I'm not getting any errors or anything and my webform loads just find. Other database implementation is working correctly. It has to be something simple I'm missing. I've also implemented the `if(!IsPostBack){ddlBatchCodeBind();` with the page load and that did not do anything either.

```
 public void ddlBatchCodeDelBind()
 {
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
         try
         {
            SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT BatchCode, BatchCodeDesc FROM BatchTable", conn);
            DataTable batch_codes = new DataTable();
            ada.Fill(batch_codes);
            ddlBatchCodeDel.DataSource = batch_codes;
            ddlBatchCodeDel.DataTextField = "BatchCodeDesc";
            ddlBatchCodeDel.DataValueField = "BatchCode";
            ddlBatchCodeDel.DataBind();
         }
         catch(SqlException ex)
         {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
         finally
         {
                conn.Close();
         }
   }

 }


<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBatchCodeDe" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"><asp:ListItem Text=Select item to Delete" Value="0"> </asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: You tagged `ASP.NET`, but I think there is no `MessageBox.Show` in `ASP.NET`, am I right?

Comment: For internal purposes, I'm using `System.Windows.Forms;` just to throw errors, but those will be changed

Comment: You mentioned `Databound event`, but I can't see any `Databound event` on the `DropDownList`, can you provide all relevant codes?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani, how about `ddlBatchCodeDel.DataBind();`?

Comment: @VDWWD as you know, we have `OnDataBound` event for some of `ASP.NET`'s controls, incl. `DropDownList`. I think it's different with `DataBind()`, what do you think?

Comment: <asp:ListItem Text=Select item to Delete" Value="0"> are you missing a quote still? after "Text="

Comment: @d_li1121 are you sure you have some data in `BatchTable`?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani 100% positive, I'm about to start a new Web Application and copy code over. Because it worked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative way that you can bind to the datatable without using `SqlDataAdapter`

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT BatchCode, BatchCodeDesc FROM BatchTable", conn))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        DataTable batch_codes = new DataTable();
        batch_codes.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        ddlBatchCodeDel.DataSource = batch_codes;
        ddlBatchCodeDel.DataTextField = "BatchCodeDesc";
        ddlBatchCodeDel.DataValueField = "BatchCode";
        ddlBatchCodeDel.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I actually so a similar example like this and tried it, same issue, no errors or anything, but it didn't work, it's so strange because I had it before and it worked. I removed it to test something else and I didn't like it when I implemented the code again, this issue came up.

Comment: can you show the `Page_Load` code then.. there is probably something happening in the Post_Back you should have an else in this code here `if(!IsPostBack){ddlBatchCodeBind();}` use the debugger and make sure the datatable actually has values..

Comment: I'm fairly new at this, I don't have an else doing anything in that block of code, it's simply the page load with the if.

Comment: you need to understand PostBacks and Page Life Cycle and this is probably what's going on you're losing your data due to a postback issue

Comment: I did read up on Page Life Cycle and understood what was going on, but I just don't know why it wasn't working despite all that. I copied my code to a new project and it worked, it is absolutely strange.Thanks for the help.

Comment: @d_li1121 you're very welcome.. glad we could get this strange thing figured out cheers

Answer (score 0):

It does here when I test it. Assuming the dropdown is correctly formatted

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBatchCodeDel" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

And you don't need `finally` when using `using`. It will close and dispose the connection for you. But it is better to wrap the `SqlDataAdapter` in `using` also since it uses the IDisposable Interface.

```
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
            using (SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT BatchCode, BatchCodeDesc FROM BatchTable", conn))
            {
                try
                {
                    DataTable batch_codes = new DataTable();
                    ada.Fill(batch_codes);
                    ddlBatchCodeDel.DataSource = batch_codes;
                    ddlBatchCodeDel.DataTextField = "BatchCodeDesc";
                    ddlBatchCodeDel.DataValueField = "BatchCode";
                    ddlBatchCodeDel.DataBind();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

And I'm pretty sure `MessageBox.Show` is a WinForms thing, not a asp.net one.

Comment: What do you mean by formatted correctly? It shows up on the page, but my initial value is the only one that shows up, if I click on it, it does not show anything.

Comment: In your snippet the L is missing `ddlBatchCodeDe`. And `Text=Select item to Delete"` is missing " after the = sign.

Comment: those are typos, but in my actual code those are not missing. I'll fix it here, but I don't know what's wrong and for the messagebox.show, that's for testing only, that will be changed.I'm using windows forms namespace to show any errors.

Comment: Maybe that's the problem? Not sure though. But as I said it works when I copy your code to my dev server. And are you 100% sure the query returns any results?

Comment: Oh yea, if I run that query in my DB it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer, but as I couldn't say this in comment, so here it is:

Please try following code and report the result. (please don't change anything else in `Page_Load` or somewhere else)

```
public void ddlBatchCodeDelBind()
{
    var x = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    x.Add(1, "Data 1");
    x.Add(2, "Data 2");
    x.Add(3, "Data 3");

    ddlBatchCodeDel.DataSource = X;
    ddlBatchCodeDel.DataTextField = "Value";
    ddlBatchCodeDel.DataValueField = "Key";
    ddlBatchCodeDel.DataBind();
}
```